# Understanding np.ix_

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Code:

```
import numpy as np

ray = [1,22,33,42,51], [61,71,812,92,103], [113,121,132,143,151], [16,172,183,19,201]
ray = np.asarray(ray)
type(ray)

ray[np.ix_([-2:],[3:4])]
```

I'd like to use index slicing and get a subarray consisting of the last two rows and the 3rd/4th columns.  My current code produces an error:

I'd also like to sum each column.  What am I doing wrong?  I cannot post a picture because I need at least 10 reputation points.

Comment: Is it correct that you want to obtain `np.array([[143, 151], [ 19, 201]])` as the result?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! @aparpara

Comment: I'd also like to sum each column as well @aparpara

Comment: Don't just say "produces an error" - show it.  It's a syntax error pointing to the ':' in `[-2:]`.  That's basic python. `-2:` is valid in indexing [], but not in list [].

Comment: I clearly stated that I cannot post a picture due to not having enough reputation points.  I just started, dude lol... @hpaulj

Comment: Can't you copy and paste text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to make a slice of an array. The most straightforward way to do it is... slicing:

```
slice = ray[-2:,3:]
```

or if you want it explicitly

```
slice = ray[-2:,3:5]
```

See it explained in [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

But if you do want to use `np.ix_` for some reason, you need

```
slice = ray[np.ix_([-2,-1],[3,4])]
```

You can't use `:` here, because `[]` here don't make a slice, they construct lists and you should specify explicitly every row number and every column number you want in the result. If there are too many consecutive indices, you may use `range`:

```
slice = ray[np.ix_(range(-2, 0),range(3, 5))]
```

And to sum each column:

```
slice.sum(0)
```

0 means you want to reduce the 0th dimension (rows) by summation and keep other dimensions (columns in this case).

Comment: Thank you so much.  If I had enough reputation points, I'd upvote your answer. @aparpara